# iPad 1 update from 5.1.1 to 7.1

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

How can I update iPad 1 from iOS 5.1.1 to iOS 7.1?

I tried checking for updates but I get a message "your software is up to date".

Comment: You won't. It's not supported. I'm just looking for citable content...

Comment: http://www.apple.com/ios/features/ You need to scroll down nearly to the bottom of the page to see the supported devices.

Answer (score 9):

#### You can't install iOS 7 (or even iOS 6) on an iPad 1.

[image: iOS 7 is compatible with…]

<sup>Source: http://www.apple.com/ios/features/</sup>

The last version of iOS capable of being installed on an iPad 1 is iOS 5.1.1 and since this is the version that you are currently on there are no updates available.

Answer (score 1):

This just isn’t possible.

From [Apple's Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202578):

> iOS 6 is not available for the iPhone 3G or earlier, iPod touch (3rd generation) or earlier, and iPad (1st generation).

[iOS 7](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1682?viewlocale=en_US&locale=es_ES)

> **System requirements**
>   iPhone 4 and later
>   iPad 2 and later
>   iPad mini
>   iPod touch (5th generation)

[iOS 8](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1758?viewlocale=en_US)

> **System requirements**
>   iPhone 4s or later
>   iPad 2 or later
>   iPad mini or later
>   iPod touch (5th gen)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html), the latest version of iOS supported by the original iPad is 5.1.1, so the answer is that within the constraints of the question (no jailbreaking, etc.) you can't upgrade beyond 5.1.1. Sorry.